# Difficulty with updating Class in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I've just started with pygame and am struggling to call .update_y on block_list, in past tutorials similar attempts have called the method from the class and comparing this to other peoples code I can't see anything I'm obviously doing wrong but I receive the error "AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'update_x' every time

Any help would be appreciated

```
import pygame, random

# DEFINITIONS
PURPLE = (147, 112, 219)
BLACK  = (  0,   0,   0)
GREEN  = ( 34, 139,  34)    
WHITE  = (255, 255, 255)

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """
    This class is for the targets to hit and player
    """
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        """
        Constructor that deals with dimensions of target
        """

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.x_change = 2
        self.y_change = 2
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.reverse = True
        self.move_count = 0

    def update_x(self):
        if self.reverse:
            self.rect.x +=.1
            self.move_count +=.1
            if self.move_count > 20:
                self.reverse = False
                self.move_count = 0
        else:
            self.rect.x -=.1
            self.move_count +=.1
            if self.move_count > 20:
                self.reverse = True
                self.move_count = 0

    def bullet_movement(self):
        self.rect.y += 1


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([WIDTH, HEIGHT])

# list for block targets
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# list for all sprites
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# list for player
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

x = 10
y = 10

# create targets
for column in range(4):
    y += 50
    x = 55
    for row in range (7):
        target = Block(PURPLE, 50, 5)
        target.rect.y = y
        target.rect.x = x
        x += 100

        block_list.add(target)
        all_sprites_list.add(target)

# create shields
x = 90
for shield in range(4):
    shield = Block(PURPLE, 95, 20)
    shield.rect.y = 450
    shield.rect.x = x
    x += 160

    all_sprites_list.add(shield)

player = Block(GREEN, 50, 5)
player.rect.y =(HEIGHT - 25)
all_sprites_list.add(player)
player_list.add(player)

game = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while game:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.rect.x += 25
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.rect.x -= 25


    screen.fill(BLACK)

    block_list.update_x()
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)


    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

See the line below:

```
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

It points to pygame.sprite.Group() which has no update_X method. Ref: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group However your update_X is defined in your Block class! Change as below and try:

```
block_list = Block()
```

Comment: Thank You very much it was an epic fail in the end as I've realised I just had to call for block in block_list, it's always the silly mistakes I come to this forum for! I am curious why if I update rect.x or rect.y by a decimal value (0.5) nothing happens? I want my sprites to move slower but they do nothing if I go between 1 and 0